# Cocoa error 3840; JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: ios, json, fragment, afnetworking

I'm facing an issue with this code, and I can't tell if its the JSON or the code that creates the issue. All the parameters are NSLogged and they are valid. On the server side our dev says the request is a success and sends a JSON back in the answer. On the app side, that JSON generates a failure (and its the only one out of all the json's i'm using, aka Weather API, GoogleAPI and internal webservices).

Here is the error that I get:

> AFNETWorking : (Cocoa error 3840.) (JSON text did not start with array
>   or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

The code :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", @"application/json", nil];

    [manager POST:API_Upload parameters: @{@"firstName": [[Constante picture]hostName],
                                           @"udid":[[Constante picture]hostUDID],
                                           @"ip":[[Constante picture]hostIpAddress],
                                           @"modele":[[Constante picture]hostDevice],
                                           @"latitude":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",[[Constante picture]hostLatitude]],
                                           @"longitude":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",[[ Constante picture]hostLongitude]] ,
                                           @"temperature": [[ Constante picture]hostTemperature],
                                           @"zip": [[ Constante picture]hostZip ],
                                           @"city": [[ Constante picture]hostCity ],
                                           @"country": [[ Constante picture]hostISO],
                                           @"langue":SYSTEM_LANG
                                           } constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

// Add picture to the form
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"phototest" ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSURL *filePathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    //NSData *filePathUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSLog(@"file path = %@",filePath);

    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePathUrl name:@"picture" error:nil];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Any clue on the why?

Comment: The error message is quite clear - NSJSONSerialization was asked to process JSON data that didn't start with [ or { as any JSON data must. It would be a good idea to check the code that does the conversion and see what input it receives.

Comment: Damn. Our developer says its fine but i guess i better check it out myself...